# capistrano deploy error on ubuntu - Could not find bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

Here is the output of executing of deploy.rb with cap deploy, on ubuntu & rvm:

when executing .../bin/bundle install vendor/gem, the error comes:

```
  * executing "cd /vol/www/emclab/current && /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems"
    servers: ["12.34.56.78"]
    [12.34.56.78] executing command
*** [err :: 12.34.56.78] /home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
*** [err :: 12.34.56.78] from /home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
*** [err :: 12.34.56.78] from /home/dtt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
*** [err :: 12.34.56.78] from /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
    command finished in 624ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /vol/www/emclab/current && /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems'" on 12.34.56.78
```

Here is the output of cap invoke COMMAND='which bundle':

```
 ** [out :: 12.34.56.78] /usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Here is the deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "git://github.com/myapp/myapp.git"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "dtt"
set :use_sudo, true
set :scm_passphrase, "phrase"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/vol/www/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

server "12.34.56.78", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
#role :web, "your web-server here"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
#role :app, "your app-server here"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
#role :db,  "your primary db-server here", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"
# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
 namespace :deploy do
   task :bundle_gems do
     run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems"
   end
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Any suggestions about the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get cap to connect and tell you where bundle is installed

```
cap invoke COMMAND='which bundle'
```

If the bundle command is not found, your PATH is not set correctly. You might need to `PermitUserEnvironment` in the sshd running on that host. Then you can set the path manually in the deploy user's `.ssh/environment` file.

Comment: it is /usr/local/bin/bundle which is for older ruby ver p180. The error may be caused by sudo and rvm. The bundler was installed for ruby p290. However cap still calls bundle in ruby p180 to execute. How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: I manually run the command with: rvmsudo /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle install vendor/gems under /current. It seems going through.

Answer (score 1):

Is bundler installed on the remote machine?

Somewhere in your log it says:

```
Could not find bundler (>= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you need to create the bundler wrapper. You can do that this way(in your deploy.rb, for example)

```
require "rvm/capistrano" # http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/

# rvm-capistrano settings
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")

namespace :rvm do
  task :create_bundle_wrapper, roles: :app do
    run "rvm wrapper #{rvm_ruby_string} bundle bundle"
  end  
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "rvm:create_bundle_wrapper"
```